# Two offline steam accounts on one PC?

Tags: steam

Is there any way to have two different Steam accounts on one PC, with BOTH being in offline mode?

We have two people sharing one computer, and we'll be losing home internet in the near future. It will be a very long time before there's an affordable alternative here. Switching steam accounts seems to require going online for verification, so without an alternative only one of us will have access to our games via offline mode once this happens.

Just to be clear, we are NOT looking to run multiple games at the same time or do any sort of multiplayer. We just don't want to lose access to either of our game libraries just because steam's DRM (because that's *exactly* what it is) crap won't let us run more than one or two specific titles without steam itself running.

Buying another pc is not an option. Family Sharing is not an option. *Anything* that will require internet to function after being set up is not an option, for the same reason we need multiple accounts offline in the first place.

Comment: Tho it is not the same use case, this question suggest to use two Windows account (assuming you're on Windows). Steam could keep one account offline per Windows account. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299525/how-to-switch-between-2-steam-accounts-on-one-pc-without-having-to-enter-mobile

I don't have a PC so I can't try it, but maybe you could give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try:

- You should each have a separate username/login on the Windows PC
- You should each have a separate Steam installation somewhere in your `%USERPROFILE%` so installations cannot accidentally clobber each other while running
- You will need to login at least once while connected to the internet. After that, [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/391071/53249) shows how to update the Windows registry with your `AutoLoginUser` in case you are periodically prompted to go online to login again
- [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/299525/53249) (referenced in the comments above) also has a few answers that look promising *(some say that due to how Steam does things, you may need to resort to some trickery, but having a separate username/login seems like the best first step)*

I only have one Steam account, but I have been able to run it offline for many years without ever reconnecting. There is hope. You can do it, too.